# How to handle SQL query loop in C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, sql-delete

I have run a script in SQL Server Management Studio to test the ability of the query perform. It is a batch delete.

```
DECLARE @Deleted_Rows INT;
SET @Deleted_Rows = 1;

WHILE (@Deleted_Rows > 0)
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRANSACTION

    DELETE TOP (10000) [dbo].[TableA1] 
    WHERE [dbo].[TableA1].[Timestamp] < CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), GETDATE()-40, 112) + ' 00:00:00' AS DATETIME)

    SET @Deleted_Rows = @@ROWCOUNT;
    COMMIT TRANSACTION
    CHECKPOINT
END
```

The result are pretty good, so I intend to apply it on C# code as my main program runs in a console application. The program handles `SELECT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`.

The problem is when use for `DELETE`, an exception occurs:

> Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements

My method for `DELETE` using the script:

```
static async Task StartDeleteRecords(string machname)
{
    try
    {
        int rowsAffected = 0;
        string query = "";

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(localconnstring))
        {
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                query = @"DECLARE @Deleted_Rows INT;
SET @Deleted_Rows = 1;
WHILE (@Deleted_Rows > 0)
BEGIN
BEGIN TRANSACTION
DELETE TOP (10000)  [dbo].[@tablename]
WHERE [dbo].[@tablename].[Timestamp] < CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), GETDATE()-@intervaltime, 112) + ' 00:00:00' AS DATETIME)
SET @Deleted_Rows = @@ROWCOUNT;
COMMIT TRANSACTION
CHECKPOINT
END";

                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
                {
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tablename", tablename);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@intervaltime", intervaltime);
                    command.CommandTimeout = 0;

                    rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }

                connection.Close();

                LogEvents("Table name: " + tablename + ", Acquire records: " + lstHouseKeep.Count + ", Affected records: " + rowsAffected, EventLogEntryType.Information);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LogEvents("Exception when load data from adapter to generic list. Ex - " + ex.Message, EventLogEntryType.Error);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        LogEvents("Exception while start housekeeping records - " + ex.Message, EventLogEntryType.Error);
    }

    await Task.Delay(100);
}
```

Comment: have you tried wrapping it in stored procedure and call it from c#?

Comment: @JohnWoo you mean by create a stored procedure with parameter and pass everything to SP?

Comment: The query is invalid, you can not use parameter as table name. Also, have a look how to use transactions correctly: http://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part1.html

Comment: Its always good to go with stored procedure approach when you have multi line command. command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;